# How to determine statistical differences among locations and years for continuous (non-normal) temperature data using R

Tags: r, multiple-comparisons

I have three years of daily water temperature data from four different rivers. The temperature data are not normally distributed, so I assume I need to use a non-parametric test. I would like to compare among sites (Locations 1, 2, 3, 4) and years (Years 1, 2, 3) to determine if there are statistical differences, and if there are, where those differences exist. I would like a suggestion of what statistical test to use, and how to code it in R.
Thank you.

Comment: @Glen_b: My apologies on the terms. To be clear, the QQ plot of the temperature data is light tailed.